# How can I get a regex to check that a string only contains a char literal or escape sequence?

Tags: regex, lex

I'm trying to create a regex to verify that a given string only has a char literal or a escape sequence and that escape sequence can be ' \t ',' \\ ',' \' ' and '\**' where ** is sequence of 1 or 2 digits between 0 and 5.

**Examples:**

**1.** `'!' = true;`

**2.** `'\a' = false;`

**3.** `'\26' = false;`

**4.** `'\\' = true;`

**5.** `'\\\t' = false;`

**6.** `'\15' = true;`

**7.** `'a' = true;`

**8.** `'aa' = false;`

Here is a example of what I have so far but it doesn't work properly

```
escape \\(t|\\|\'|[0-5]{1,2})


\'                   \\begins CHARLITERAL

<CHARLITERAL>[^\n\']|{escape}     \\True condition
<CHARLITERAL>[^t\\\'\n]|\\[0-9]+  \\False condition
<CHARLITERAL>\'                   \\End CHARLITERAL
<CHARLITERAL>\n                   \\Unterminated
<CHARLITERAL><<EOF>>               \\Unterminated
```

I would think that this would work but on many of the false outputs I'm getting true.

Comment: is a backslash alone true or false?

Comment: Are you meaning  '\' ? If that´s the case it would fall in the unterminated case because it starts with the single quote " '  " and then it has the " \' " escape sequence but doesn´t have another single quote " ' " to close it.

Comment: Are you trying to match only a single character (or escape), or are you trying to match a string consisting of any number of characters and escapes?

Comment: If you're trying to just match a single one, you can't tell whether the match was successful or not until your verify that the next character is a `'`, and your pattern makes no attempt to do that.

Comment: I'm only trying to match a single character or escape

Comment: In that case, I think you are making your life more difficult by trying to use a start condition.

Comment: What about `^(.|\\[0-5][0-5]?|\\\\)$`? Not sure if lex uses the same engine as PHP though, https://regex101.com/r/HN8Akf/1

Comment: The thing is that I need to save the string, for example if it his `'\\'` it will print `CHARLITERAL ( '\\' )` but if it´s something like `'\\\t'` it would print `Invalid Char ( '\\\t' )` and that´s why I have the start the condition and why I need the false state there 
 @rici

Comment: You don't need a start condition for that. But it's always useful to describe your "complete* requirements in a question (not a comment)

Answer (score 0):

I think this particular problem is more easily solved without a start condition for the character literal. Since you want to ensure that only a single code (either a character or an escape) is presented between the single quotes, your success pattern should include both the starting and ending single quotes:

```
  /* ' does not have any special meaning to (f)lex so it does not have to be escaped */
'(['^\n\\]|\\([t'\\]|[0-5]{1,2}))'    { printf("CHARLITERAL: %s\n", yytext); }
```

Since that will match any correct character literal, you can detect incorrect literals by just matching a single quote; that pattern will only trigger if no longer match is available:

```
'                                     { printf("Invalid CHARLITERAL\n"); }
                                      /* But see below */
```

The only issue then is to figure out how to resume the scan after the error is noted, because once you find an error you cannot know for certain what the correct input would have been. All you can do is guess. (Of course, if your parser doesn't know how to do error recovery, this is all theoretical. You can just stop the scan when you hit the first error.)

One simple guess, which will often work, is to skip characters until you find either a `'` or a newline. That might skip too much, if the error was a missing closing quote, but it won't skip far too much since at most it will skip the rest of the line.

Here, you could make use of a start condition:

```
'(['^\n\\]|\\([t'\\]|[0-5]{1,2}))'    { printf("CHARLITERAL: %s\n", yytext); }
'                                     { BEGIN(BAD_CHAR_LITERAL); }
<BAD_CHAR_LITERAL>[^'\n]*'?           { printf("Bad CHARLITERAL: Skipping '%s\n", yytext);
                                        BEGIN(INITIAL);
                                      }
<BAD_CHAR_LITERAL><<EOF>>             { printf("Trailing single quote\n");
                                        return 0;
                                      }
```

The pattern in `BAD_CHARACTER_LITERAL` skips either the rest of the line or up to and including the next single quote. In the first case, it leaves the newline to be handled by the default scanner state.

Alternatively, you could use `input()` to just read characters from the input stream until you find `'` or `\n` (or EOF).